# How can I call a function in a php class?

Tags: php, class, imagick, system.drawing.imaging

This is a sample code:

[sample code](https://gist.github.com/giorrrgio/3904046#file-imagineresizer-php)

I want to call it in another page:

```
include 'root of class file';
$r = new ImagineResizer();
```

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ImagineResizer' not found in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\example.com\webroot\images.php on line 13
```

Also call the function:

```
$r->resize('c:/test1.jpg', 'c:/test2.jpg');
```

Comment: Do they lie in the same folder?

Comment: `use Acme\MyBundle\Service\ImageResizer;`

Comment: you have to include the class file not just the root folder of the file.

Comment: You need to specify the namespace before the class name and after the `new` keyword. `$r = new Acme\MyBundle\Service\ImageResizer()`

Comment: No but the path is true:echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/core/images/functions.php';

Comment: Can you put you functions.php into your question?

Comment: @KhorneHoly : All is here: https://gist.github.com/giorrrgio/3904046#file-imagineresizer-php

Comment: @AnotherGuy Thanks but didn't work/same error

Comment: Try require, not include, to catch error. Your class file is not loaded.

Comment: If you are within another namespace at the same time you would have to prepend the backslash to indicate that this should be loaded with the global namespace as root namespace and not the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in your sample code the class is located in another namespace :

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Imagine\Image\ImagineInterface;
use Imagine\Image\BoxInterface;
use Imagine\Image\Point;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

class ImagineResizer {
    //-- rest of code     
}
```

To use a class in another namespace you need to point out where the file is :
First include the class (manual or with autoloading)

Then u can create an instance in 2 ways. First way with the `use`-keyword

```
use Acme\MyBundle\Service\ImageResizer;
$object = new ImageResizer();
```

Or point to the class absolute :

```
$object = new \Acme\MyBundle\Service\ImageResizer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this will help you out some:

1. Make sure you include the actual file - not just the folder where it lies.
2. Make sure that the file you're calling the class from uses the same namespace as your class file. If it doesn't, you have to call the class using the full namespace.
3. Profit.

The namespaces really had my patience go for a spin when I started using them, but once you're used to it it's not too hard. I would recommend using an autoloader though. It's a bit of a hassle to set up, but once it's done it helps out a bunch.

- **Namespaces:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php
- **Autoloader:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php